# How does `matplotlib` adjust plot to figure size?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, librosa

How does `matplotlib` ensure that a dataset can be within plot with specified size.

How do i from a plot stored as numpy, How do i read the color of the pixels illustration a datapoint (0,4) -  in the plot.

example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image
import librosa
import librosa.display
from matplotlib import cm


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
min = -1.828067
max = 22.70058
data =  np.random.uniform(low=min, high=max, size=(474,40))
librosa.display.specshow(data.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
raw_input("sadas")

convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
numpy_output_static = convert(data.T)
plt.imshow(numpy_output_static, aspect = 'auto')
plt.show()
raw_input("asds")
```

First plot being :

[image]

Second plot being:

[image]

so the first has been resized to plot size 12,4 where the last basically plots the same data but just using the data shape as size... how do i change that?

Librosa just performs pcolormesh according to the [GitHub source code](https://github.com/librosa/librosa/blob/183796037d79e98b1b20003d6a58fb34bb610ec0/librosa/display.py#L678)

Comment: are you plotting the 30x30 using ``plot`` or ``imshow`` or what? it is not clear to me what you are asking. Do you have some sample code?

Comment: hopes it helps..

Comment: Well, not sure if I get the question, but I will give an answer. With ``pcolormesh``, you need to specify the x, y coordinates, as such: ``plt.pcolormesh(x,y,z)``. Each of x, y, z are 30x30 meshes. If in your code you only specify the color values as in ``plt.pcolormesh(z)``, then the x and y are automatically set to be a integer coordinates from 0 to 29.

Comment: added an example.

Comment: how do we know what figure-sizing parameters and plotting methods `librosa` used?

Comment: You need to include a clear problem description. What would you like to achieve, what do you get and in how far does it not meet your expectations?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define another figure with its own size for the second figure.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
from PIL import Image
import librosa
import librosa.display
from matplotlib import cm


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
min = -1.828067
max = 22.70058
data =  np.random.uniform(low=min, high=max, size=(474,40))
librosa.display.specshow(data.T,sr=16000,x_axis='frames',y_axis='mel',hop_length=160,cmap=cm.jet)
plt.show()
raw_input("sadas")

convert = plt.get_cmap(cm.jet)
numpy_output_static = convert(data.T)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,4))
plt.imshow(numpy_output_static, aspect = 'auto')
plt.show()
raw_input("asds")
```

Comment: Yes... But if I stored this plot as a figure,  how do i using the new defined figure extract datapoint row 0 column 0..